# Node.js killed due to out of memory

Tags: node.js, memory

I'm running `Node.js` on a server with only `512MB` of `RAM`. The problem is when I run a script, it will be killed due to out of memory.

By default the `Node.js` memory limit is `512MB`. So I think using `--max-old-space-size` is useless.

Follows the content of `/var/log/syslog`:

```
Oct  7 09:24:42 ubuntu-user kernel: [72604.230204] Out of memory: Kill process 6422 (node) score 774 or sacrifice child
Oct  7 09:24:42 ubuntu-user kernel: [72604.230351] Killed process 6422 (node) total-vm:1575132kB, anon-rss:396268kB, file-rss:0kB
```

Is there a way to get rid of out of memory without upgrading the memory? (like using persistent storage as additional RAM)

Update:
It's a scraper which uses node module request and cheerio. When it runs, it will open hundreds or thousands of webpage (but not in parallel)

Comment: Without knowing what kind of data is using that much amount of memory and how you work with that data it is hard to tell. Tools like redis can help you to cache frequently used data outside of nodejs.

Comment: Your options for how to reduce your memory consumption are entirely dependent upon what you're doing in your app that is consuming the most memory.  Since you don't share any of that with us, it's a little hard for us to know what the choices are.  You probably need to start by understanding what is using the most memory.

Answer (score 0):

If you're giving Node access to every last megabyte of the available 512, and it's still not enough, then there's 2 ways forward:

1. Reduce the memory requirements of your program. This may or may not be possible. If you want help with this, you should post another question detailing your functionality and memory usage.
2. Get more memory for your server. `512mb` is not much, especially if you're running other services (such as databases or message queues) which require in-memory storage.

There is the 3rd possibility of using `swap` space (disk storage that acts as a memory backup), but this will have a strong impact on performance. If you still want it, Google how to set this up for your operating system, there's a lot of articles on the topic. This is OS configuration, not Node's.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but may be this answer will help people. Using --max-old-space-size is not useless.

Before Nodejs 12, versions have an heap memory size that depends on the OS (32 or 64 bits). So, following documentations, on 64-bit machines that (the old generation alone) would be 1400 MB, far away from your 512mb.

From Nodejs12, heap size take care of system RAM; however Nodejs' heap isn't the only thing in memory, especially if your server isn't dedicated to it. So set the --max-old-space-size permit to have a limit regarding the old memory heap, and if your application comes closer, the garbage collector will be triggered and will try to free memory.

I've write a post about how I've observed this: https://loadteststories.com/nodejs-kubernetes-an-oom-serial-killer-story/